# Pip does not recognize torchaudio libary

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torchaudio

When i try the command:

```
pip install torchaudio
```

i get this error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchaudio
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchaudio
```

I use windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing this:

```
 pip install torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Found on the github.

https://github.com/pytorch/audio

Comment: Does not work for me. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer did not work for me in the colab environment. However, `pip install torchaudio==0.4.0` installed the module.